# MFC Image Button with transparency

Tags: c++, button, mfc, transparency

I'm updating an MFC dialog with a number of buttons on it.

At present, the dialog has a Picture control covering the whole dialog providing a patterned background. On top of that, each button is a CBitmapButton using (opaque) images carefully generated to match the area of background they cover.

It would obviously be much easier if the images could be created as mostly transparent, so the background shows through automatically. However, I can't work out how to get MFC to render transparent images correctly in this case.

I understand that I might want a different class to CBitmapButton, or need to write a custom subclass; that's fine, but I don't know where to start. It would be nice to support 32-bit BMP or PNG with alpha channel, but I'd settle for the "specified colour should be transparent" type.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best way to do it, but what I'd do is create a custom CButton derived class (assuming that you're actually using the rest of the CButton functionality), then override the DrawItem function to put your custom draw code in.

For the image itself I'd use a Bitmap GDI+ object (which will allow you to load either BMPs or PNGs with alpha channels) then use the regular DrawImage function to draw the bitmap.

If you're going to put PNGs into your resource file then you need to put them in as a "PNG" type.  Make sure when you look in the resource file code that the entry looks like

IDB_PNG1    PNG    "C:\temp\test.png"

and doesn't try to treat it as a BITMAP resource otherwise you'll have problems loading them.

**Edit**

Putting my response here so I can post code. Yes, I meant to derive a custom class from CButton, then add a Gdiplus::Bitmap member variable. Here is roughly what you'll need to do to get it to work, though I haven't checked that the code actually compiles and works, but hopefully you'll get the idea. It's not the most efficient way to do it, but if you've not done much custom drawing before then it does have the advantage of being simple!

```
void CMyButton::LoadImage(const int resourceID)
{
    m_pBitmap = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(resourceID));
    ASSERT(m_pBitmap);
}

void CMyButton::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct) 
{
    ASSERT(lpDrawItemStruct->CtlType == ODT_BUTTON);

    CRect rcClient;
    GetClientRect(&rcClient);
    if (lpDrawItemStruct->itemState & ODS_SELECTED)
    {
        // If you want to do anything special when the button is pressed, do it here
        // Maybe offset the rect to give the impression of the button being pressed?
        rcClient.OffsetRect(1,1);
    }
    Graphics gr(lpDrawItemStruct->hDC);
    gr.DrawImage(m_pBitmap, rcClient.left, rcClient.top);
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to drawing stuff in the MFC. Are you suggesting I subclass CButton to have a member of type [`Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then override the subclass's `DrawItem` to instead call `DrawImage` on the member Bitmap? What needs to go in an overridden `DrawItem`? I can't find an appropriate `DrawImage` method in the MSDN docs. Could you post some code snippets?

Comment: FromResource is returning NULL. How can I determine why the load is failing?

Comment: Try using GetModuleHandle(NULL) instead of NULL as the first argument to the Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromResource function.

Comment: No better. I also have the same problem if I try a PNG resource instead of a BITMAP; or use `FromFile`. Is there no way I can ask the code what the reason was?

Comment: Sorry, I've just remembered you need to initialise GDI+ (one of those things you do then forget about). You need "GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput; GdiplusStartup(&m_gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);" in your application startup, then "GdiplusShutdown(m_gdiplusToken);" when it shuts down.

Comment: Ok, that gets the BITMAP to load. Sadly, it's not transparent (it's black where the transparency should be, assuming AlphaConv did it's job; and a PNG resource now results in the Bitmap having `lastResult==InvalidParamter`); and it's not displaying the whole image - GetClientRect is returning much smaller than the image size - what governs the ClientRect size? It seems to be larger than the size of the control.

Comment: The ClientRect should be the size of the button. If you want to stretch the image to fill the button you'll need to use one of the other DrawImage overrides which take source and destination rects. Check that your image has the alpha channel and not just black when you view it in an external editor, then make sure your Bitmap has loaded it as a 32bit image by checking it's image format.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a hunt for an appropriate DrawImage. Reading the image in a hex editor, I can see that it definitely has 32 bits per pixel, and that the Alpha channel is carrying some areas of 0. I can't find an image editor that will render it as transparent (even FireFox doesn't). How do I check the image format of the Bitmap object?

Comment: Update: Google Chrome treats it as transparent, so it definitely is.