# Adding bitmap to button in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, bitmap

I want to create a custom button in MFC as following,

[image]

Its a png image and I need to handle button clicked / button hover events each having different images.
How do I get to this in VC++ / MFC

Comment: possible duplicate of [MFC Image Button with transparency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293298/mfc-image-button-with-transparency)

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [docu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984522%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). There is a function CMFCButton::SetImage that takes 3 images normal, hot and disabled.

Comment: I don't think this will work for a png image.  You can, however, create and render the image using GDI+.